# In MongoLab Sandbox: When using await on IMongoCollection<SomeType>.UpdateOneAsync it occasionally fails

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

#### Using MongoLab Sandbox:

With this class:

```
class Block {
    ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    List<Item> ListOfItems;
}
```

I'm testing the following method, that just adds and `Item` to certain `Block`'s `ListOfItems` field:

```
async Task AddItem(Block block, Item item) {
    var updateDefinition = Builders<Block>.Update
        .AddToSet(b => b.ListOfItems, item);
            
    var result = await blocksCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
        b => b.BlockId == block.BlockId, updateDefinition);
    
    // however the synchronous version works:
    // var result = blocksCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
    //      b => b.BlockId == block.BlockId, updateDefinition).Result;
    
    if (result.ModifiedCount != 1)
        throw new DbException();
}
```

This is the test:

```
async Task AddItemsTest() {
    await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(
        i => AddItem(certainBlock, new Item())));
}
```

Now if I run it asynchronously (with `await` on `blocksCollection.UpdateOneAsync` method), sometimes the `result.ModifiedCount` is 0 and not 1 (approx. 1 to 17 times), which throws the `DbException`.

When I run it synchronously (no `await`, with `.Result`), everything runs fine and all 20 items are added.

Why is that? could it be `MongoLab`'s (mlab.com, recently...) limitation on sandboxed environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
async Task AddItem(Block block, Item item) {
    var updateDefinition = Builders<Block>.Update
        .AddToSet(b => b.ListOfItems, item);

    var result = await blocksCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
        b => b.BlockId == block.BlockId, updateDefinition);
static object locker = new object();
    // however the synchronous version works:
    // var result = blocksCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
    //      b => b.BlockId == block.BlockId, updateDefinition).Result;
lock(locker)
   {
    if (result.ModifiedCount != 1)
        throw new DbException();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work. But to be honest, it doesn't make any sense anyway... `result` is local variable and never returned nor saved, so there is no chance for it to be shared among threads.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to be `MongoLab`/`mLab` issue. When switched to Azure's DocumentDB ([with same code btw, apparently they also support MongoDB now...](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-connect-mongodb-account/)) it all just worked, with no code change...

I'm pondering what to do now, start ping-ponging with their support or just waive...